# Problem with label and precision

Tags: numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I need to define a function that depends on a variable taking values on discrete values, for example:

```
xi = 0.04;
xf = 0.5;
dx = 0.001;
Table[f[x] = x^2, {x, xi, xf, dx}];
```

Next, I wish to take, for example, its second derivative.

```
secondder=Table[{x, (f[x - dx] - 2*f[x] + f[x + dx])/dx^2}, {x, xi + dx,xf - dx, dx}];
```

The problem is that when Mathematica is computing the increments, it adds precision, that is:

```
xi + dx + dx + dx
```

gives

```
0.043000000000000003`
```

so it doesn't return the value of f[0.043] previously defined. I have tried SetPrecicion, SetAccuracy, but I can't make it work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could use arbitrary precision definitions for your values: `xi = 1/25; xf = 1/2; dx = 1/1000;`, with the rest of the code unchanged.
- Alternatively, you could call `f[Round[x - dx, dx]]` instead of `f[x - dx]` in your calculation of the derivative:

  ```
  secondder =
    Table[
      {x, (f[Round[x - dx, dx]] - 2*f[x] + f[x + dx])/dx^2},
      {x, xi + dx, xf - dx, dx}
    ]
  ```
- You can achieve the same result using:

  ```
  table = Table[x^2, {x, xi, xf, dx}];
  Transpose[{
    Range[xi + dx, xf - dx, dx],
    Differences@Differences@table/dx^2
  }]

  (* Out: {{0.041, 2.}, {0.042, 2.}, ...., {0.498, 2.}, {0.499, 2.}} *)
  ```
- I am not sure why you couldn't define `Clear[f]; f[x_] := x^2` instead. Even if you are calculating the derivative numerically, you should always be able to calculate the function's value for any value of the independent variable...

Comment: thanks for your reply! This was just a simple example, my 'f' doesn't have a closed form, I evaluate it numerically. Unfortunately neither the Round or Difference solution seem to work: if you evaluate it you will see that things like 0.043000000000000003` remain. But I liked the Round solution and I am trying to make it work.

Comment: I forgot to say: using arbitrary precision xi = 1/25; xf = 1/2; dx = 1/1000 is not an option because I have to storage a large ammount of data.

I am puzzled by this! Table[FullForm[Round[x - dx, dx]], {x, xi + dx, xf - dx, dx}]

Comment: @aprendiz the `.00000000003` stuff are due to representing machine-precision decimals in binary form. They won't really "go away" as long as you are using machine-precision. Also, could you say again why the `Differences` approach won't work for you to continue further?

Comment: I was wrong, the Differences approach does work, thank you!